# search Junwoo's mistake!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Junwoo calculated the shortest distance from the starting vertex to all vertices on five different graphs with all edges of length 1. However, there was a mistake in haste so we got the shortest distance wrong for one graph. Find the wrong graph when given only part of the graph: The number written within each vertex is the shortest distance that Junwoo has found.[image]

Comment: I see the answer.  Now... how did I know what the answer was?  Remember what the numbers represent here... the distance from the given vertex to our target and edges all have length $1$.  If I have a vertex whose distance to the target was... $5$ for instance, then all neighbors of that would need to be $4$ or higher, right?  Because suppose that it had a neighbor who was $2$.  Then I could have gone from the vertex currently labeled as being distance $5$ away to the vertex labeled distance $2$ away, then move those two spaces more and get to the target in a total of three moves, less than $5$

Comment: TLDR: the distance of a neighbor of $x$ to the target can never be less than $1$ less than the distance of $x$ to the target (*since edge weights are all $1$*).

Comment: Thank you I can understand what you mean.